# Maximum value of CURLOPT_TIMEOUT

Tags: php, curl

I use [`cURL library`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get the content of current URL. So I wonder, what is the maximum value for CURLOPT_TIMEOUT option of [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) function ? I also looked at [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) but found nothing about it. Is it possible to set no time limit to this option? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It is possible to set no time limit to `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` by simply setting the timeout to `0`.**

Do take into account that good programming normally expects the unexpected. So if you want to make sure your code doesn't hang... and you want to wait extra-long, double or triple what you are expecting to be your maximum value but don't leave that thread there hanging eternally if something goes wrong.